# What does Mail.deliver return when a mail is sent using ruby mail gem? or using response to determine validity of email id no regex please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

See the following code snippet:

```
def deliver_email
    mailResponse = Mail.deliver do
      to 'someEmail@whichDoesntExist.bla'
      from 'Unspecified <info@unspecified.com>'
      subject 'Email Delivery Test'
      text_part do
        body(
          "email Body"
        )
      end
      html_part do
        content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        body("email Body")
      end
    end
rescue Exception => exception
  p "Invalid Email ID"
end
```

I am using ruby "mail" gem to send mail, I want to print something if an invalid email is found. I don't want to use regular expression, instead I want to use the response of Mail.deliver to determine the validity of email. The above code snippet doesn't go into rescue block even if the email ID is invalid ! 

**My smtp setup**

```
Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, {
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port => '587',
    :user_name => 'sampleUsername',
    :password => 'samplePassword',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  }
end
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: p mailResponse prints out the email :(

Comment: by invalid do you mean invalid format or something else?

Comment: by invalid I mean email id doesn't exist kind of thing...like for example, someEmail@whichDoesntExist.bla , this email satisfies a valid email format if tested using regular expression but I think the domain doesn't exist...So whenever these kind of emails are entered some error must be thrown from the deliver function

Comment: That depends on how your smtp server is setup - it may accept messages instantly and send a bounce message at some later date if it can't resolve the domain.

Comment: What property that I need to add/change in the server setup which catches delivery failure exceptions ? I think there is a "raise_delivery_errors" flag which I saw in ruby mail gem source code but I'm kinda lost in implementing it

Comment: Hey, added SMTP setup to the question

Comment: By smtp setup I meant how the smtp server itself is configured (which in your case isn't under your control). My point is that a bad email address won't always result in an immediate failure.

Comment: okay Thanks...So, no workaround except for pattern matching I guess?